# Запись на слейв сервере в mysql

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте!
Помогите, пожалуйста понять:
у меня есть 2 сервера MySQL настроена репликация master-slave
с мастера все обновления проходят на слейв.
Но на слейве возможно изменение данных, я могу проинсертить записи или проапдейтить их в реплицированной таблице и данные поменяются, но только на слейве.
Можно ли как то заблокировать данную возможность, я хочу что бы со слейва были доступны только операции чтения, а на мастере чтения и записи.
Это делается на уровне прав пользователей или у меня где то в конфиге mysql и реплицкации ошибка?

Comment: да, с помощью глобальной переменной `read_only`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_read_only https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-solutions-backups-read-only.html